# How to change props in a component passed into another component as props

Tags: reactjs

I have a Screens component being passed into a Modal component as the screens prop. Inside Modal I'm rendering it thusly...

```
{props.screens()}
```

This displays fine but I need a way to change the Screens components props from within Modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), which allows you to clone an element and add new props.

```
function myComponent(props) {

return <> {React.cloneElement(props.screens, {someNewProp:"value"}, children)} </>;

}
```